# Do I need timezone support in Django?

Tags: python, django, timezone

I am developing a Django application that is based around event information. My client is sending all date/time information in UTC and making the conversion to local time. These are then sent to the server as a string. Furthermore, I'm using Postgres as the DB which also stores information in UTC.

Timezone support is active, but I am placing naive datetimes into Django and am receiving warnings. Do I even need time zone support for my application?

If so, how can I resolve the warnings?

Answer (score 0):

```
USE_TZ = True # to activate time zone setting.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago' # set your timezone
```

When you activate time zone setting, DJango shows warning for each time you set **Naive** date time in your cod. Nothing to panic. You need to change your code to use **Aware** date time step by step.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#concepts

```
from django.utils.timezone import utc, now

class SomeModel(Model):
    schedule = django_models.DateTimeField(default=now)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly encourage that you use [pytz module](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/). It makes working with timezones less painful.